# What do houses require to advance?

Tags: anno-2070

I seem to be missing something about how the house upgrading system works. I seem to have fulfilled all the obvious requirements: both population classes' needs are fulfilled to 100%, both classes are at their maximum current capacity and happy enough to keep moving in. The warehouses have enough tools, construction blocks, carbon and even wood (not used by the particular faction I'm having this problem with) for them to upgrade. Yet they won't upgrade.

[image]

Pictured: the particular situation that keeps me stuck in the campaign, appalling lack of **SCIENCE** and **PROGRESS**.

So what are the general requirements for a house to become eligible for an upgrade, *regardless of faction*? Are there any additional *faction-specific* requirements?

Comment: [This](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39769/why-wont-my-researchers-advance-further-in-sandbox-mode) is also potentially related.

Comment: @FAE Thanks. The first one is similar, but has no (accepted) answer. I'm fairly certain all of the needs mentioned there are provided in my game, but they still won't advance. I would also like a more general answer suitable for every faction.

Comment: @Pvt.Grichmann - it would be worth adding that information to the question so emphasise the differences between your question and the potential duplicate.

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks. There, I rewrote it now to be more obviously a general question, not one about a specific situation. Better now?