# Anno 2070 Deep Ocean Expansion cannot advance researchers to geniues

Tags: anno-2070

Anno 2070, continuous game, Deep Ocean expansion is present (i.e. I have build functional food factories, I have the thermal power station available to me).  I have over 5,000 researchers who have all their needs satisfied yet they are not advancing to the Genius level. I have no Geniuses at all.  What am I missing?

Also, before someone points out that my question is a duplicate of [Why won't my Researchers advance further in sandbox mode?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39769/why-wont-my-researchers-advance-further-in-sandbox-mode) let me tell you that it's not a duplicate.  My question is about Anno 2070 with the Deep Ocean Expansion which does have a 3rd Tech tier, see [Geniuses' Residences](http://anno2070.wikia.com/wiki/Geniuses%27_Residences).

[image]

This is the tax rate, they are euphoric, but I can't seem to lower the tax rate further into the dark green, it just snaps back to where it is now.

[image]

All the needs say that they are 100% satisfied.

**UPDATE:** Something is definitely not right.  I don't have access to the Immunity Drug Manufacturers either, even though I have more than enough Researchers to unlock it.

Comment: Do you have zero geniuses?  Or just a section of your researchers won't upgrade?

Comment: @Frank Zero geniuses, 420 lab assistants, 5,082 researchers, and zero geniuses.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of their needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mystery solved.  I did not have the Deep Ocean expansion.
Submarines are included in the normal Anno 2070 and so are geothermal plants, those alone are not a sufficient indicator that one has the Deep Ocean expansion.  In addition I have found that some players who reported that they actually did have Deep Ocean still had issues with advancing geniuses.

There are two possible solutions to that problem; either the Deep Ocean expansion pack has not been enabled in the launcher, or the game was created prior to purchasing Deep Ocean.  If one purchased Deep Ocean after the core Anno 2070 then a new game has to be started to include Deep Ocean features.