# Sinking deep down the ocean in Anno 2070 - Deep Ocean

Tags: anno-2070

In Anno 2070 - Deep Ocean, I cannot scroll down to sink under sea level, even though I can see the shadow of an underwater base with submarines hanging around. Do I need to wait for some event to be able to sink underwater? Or do I have a faulty copy of some kind?

Answer (score 1):

You need to unlock either eco engineers or tycoon engineers before having access to trimaran and SAAT tech. You will also need Deep Ocean DLC to have access to underwater platform. Check [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/167131/anno-2070-deep-ocean-expansion-cannot-advance-researchers-to-geniues).